# vue.js sticky nav bar only executed one time and having error: scrollTop is always 0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sticky, scrolltop

all. I was trying to do the sticky bar, but having issues:

1. If i wrote as below, the `navBaroffsetTop` is always 0, and the function `fixNavBar()` only execute one time when the page got loaded.
   [image]

HTML:

> ```
> <template>
>   <div class="navigators" :class="{ navBarFixed: isFixed }" ref="navigators">
>    html content
>   </div>
> </template>
> ```

CSS:

```
.navBarFixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 655px;
}
```

Script:

```
 data() {
    return {
      isFixed: false
    };
  },
 methods: {
    fixNavBar: function(e) {
      let navBar = this.$refs.navigators;
      let navBaroffsetTop = navBar.offsetTop;
      let documentScrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
      console.log(1);
      console.log(documentScrollTop);
      if (
        documentScrollTop >= navBaroffsetTop ||
        document.documentElement.scrollTop >= navBaroffsetTop
      ) {
        this.isFixed = true;
        }
    }
}

  mounted: function() {
    window.onscroll = this.fixNavBar()
  }
```

2. the reason i was putting the `window.onload()` in the `mounted` lifecycle is that i was putting it in the fuction `fixNavBar()` but it only worked in a cheating way and when the page reloaded it stopped working, which i guess is because when i call the function `fixNavBar()` in the mounted lifecycle, it excuted only one time. In the meanwhile, it still has the

> `navBaroffsetTop` printed as always 0

and also the error

> can't read property`.offsetTop` of undefined

in the console.

In this case, code was as below:

```
fixNavBar: function (e) {
    let navBar = this.$refs.navigators;
    let navBaroffsetTop = navBar.offsetTop;
    let documentScrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    window.onscroll = function () {
        console.log(1);
        console.log(documentScrollTop);
        if (
            documentScrollTop >= navBaroffsetTop ||
            document.documentElement.scrollTop >= navBaroffsetTop
        ) {
            this.isFixed = true;
        }
    };
}
```

`mounted: function() {this.fixNavBar();}`

Comment: `window.onscroll = this.fixNavBar()` should be like `window.onscroll = this.fixNavBar`

Comment: if you put parentheses after function name, this will call the function and assign the value to `window.onscroll` while `window.onscroll` is expecting a handler of type function.

Answer (score 0):

The function executes immidately because you are calling it with ();

Just your code to this:

`window.onscroll = this.fixNavBar;`